# Negating Parts in Blender and Exporting Incorrectly

Tags: model, 3d, rendering, render, modeling

I was using the plugin Bool Tool, but when I exported it, it looked like this:[

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXgaQ.png)

It shows this in the Windows 10 3D viewer and some random online 3D viewer so I doubt it's 'renderer-specific'

I wasn't expecting this because in Blender it shows this:

[image]

Is there something I'm missing? Do I need to enable something, or is this just not possible?
I was expecting the Bool Tool to persist in exports.. Is there something in settings or so?

I created the model on a different computer which I currently don't have access to so I'm not sure which version of Blender I used...

Comment: Sorry about that, I forgot that was a thing... I'll make sure to post it there next time..

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be asked at https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Comment: No. I'll leave it here. I don't see the "big problem"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try pressing `tab` to get into edit mode, `a` to select all faces, and `Ctrl+T` to triangulate faces before exporting. Looks like either the file format or the viewers are struggling with the number of faces.

Keep in mind this is destructive so you can't go back... might be wise to do in an exporting copy of the `.blend` file.

Original answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/226841/125494